# Problem Adding PATH to ~/.zshrc

Tags: environment-variables, macintosh, homebrew, brew

I am having an issue adding a path variable on my zsh.

This is the warning that was produced:

```
Warning: Homebrew's sbin was not found in your PATH but you have installed
formulae that put executables in /usr/local/sbin.
Consider setting the PATH for example like so:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can safely follow the advice of the warning and run:

```
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

The warning will then disappear.

Comment: Thanks, this works